# Is it possible to set long startup sound for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, boot

I'm trying to set a *.wav file as Windows (7 Ultimate) log on sound. The sound file is more than 1 minute in length. When I log onto Windows, it never play the sound. I think there is a limitation in the length of sound files that can be played by windows sound in Windows XP. Is such limitation still exists in Windows 7? How can I play a 1 minute sound file every time I log on to Windows?

Note, I don't want to put the sound file in startup folder or do something similar. I want to set the sound file as 'Windows Log on' sound.

Comment: Have you tried it with various quality settings on the file to reduce it's physical size?  For example a 16kHz 8-bit audio file may sound okay but would be a heck of a lot smaller than a 48kHz 24-bit audio file and may potentially work if it's a file size limit that Windows is working to rather than play time...

Comment: @Mokubai, your trick works. Now the file is 1.4 MB and Windows can play it. Can you please post your comment as answer?

Comment: I've undeleted and edited my earlier answer to match the fix :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried it with various quality settings on the file to reduce it's physical size?

For example a 16kHz 8-bit audio file may sound okay but would be a heck of a lot smaller than a 48kHz 24-bit audio file.

This could potentially work if it's a file size limit that Windows is working to rather than the play time of the file...

Answer (score 3):

I've done some research on this topic, and it appears that it's just not possible, other that the startup menu option. The issue is that that file must be stored in RAM, and during boot, the system needs that space. The limit was put in due to performance reasons, and there doesn't seem to be a workaround.

Comment: What is the quantitative value of *the limit*? Is it 50 KB? Or 5 seconds? Or something else? Does it differ for each version of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a task to do that on Windows Task Scheduler. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756979.aspx